# Loop for calculating monthly means

Tags: r, loops, mean, raster

I have a Raster Layer with 371 layers:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 35, 17, 372  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 2.5, 1.267606  (x, y)
extent      : -1.25, 41.25, 27.25352, 71.61972  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
names       :  clt_301,  clt_302,   clt_303,  clt_304,   clt_305,  clt_306, ... 
min values  : 18.14771, 11.93175,  5.477096, 14.04819,  4.086611,  0.00000, ... 
max values  : 99.79733, 99.92499, 99.412560, 98.52460, 95.505341, 91.06673, ... 
time (days) : 2040-01-16 to 2070-12-16
```

Each represents a month. So the whole raster file contains data for a total of 31 years. The layers are not named by months but in ascending chronology from hurs_301 to hurs_672. Now I need to calculate the average per month over all years (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December). The final goal is to generate a raster file that contains 12 layers, per layer the average of one month ( 1: layer average January over all 31 years, 2nd layer average February over all years etc.).
I have thought of the following steps: I create a loop that names the layers from 1-12 and then calculate the average of the layers per month and stack them to a raster.

```
ipsl_hurs_126_future <- raster(ipsl_hurs_126_future) #read in ispl_hurs_126_future as a raster

# Create a vector of month names
month_names <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

# Create an empty RasterBrick to store the monthly means
monthly_means <- raster(nrow=nrow(ipsl_hurs_126_future), ncol=ncol(ipsl_hurs_126_future))


# Loop through each month
for (month_idx in 1:12) {
  # Initialize an empty RasterLayer to store the averaged result
  avg_layer <- NULL
  
  # Get the month's layer indices
  month_layers <- seq(month_idx, 371, 12)
  
  # Loop through the month's layers and calculate the average
  for (layer_idx in month_layers) {
    current_layer <- ipsl_hurs_126_future[[layer_idx]]

 if (is.null(avg_layer)) {
      avg_layer <- current_layer
    } else {
      avg_layer <- avg_layer + current_layer
    }
  }
  
  # Divide the accumulated sum by the number of layers to get the average
  avg_layer <- avg_layer / length(month_layers)
  
  # Set a meaningful name for the averaged layer
  averaged_layer_name <- paste("avg_hurs_", month_names[month_idx], sep = "")
  
  # Assign the averaged layer to the RasterBrick
  monthly_means[[month_idx]] <- avg_layer
}

# Print the resulting monthly means SpatRaster
print(monthly_means)

class(monthly_means)
```

Unfortunately i end up with this:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 35, 17, 595  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 21.17647, 5.142857  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Which is not what i want to have in the end.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!